# Workaround for Delphi 2007 error "Unable to rename unit.pas to __history\unit..."

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

In the Delphi 2007 IDE, I'm hoping there's a configuration option I could turn on to turn off the generation of __HISTORY folders.

I am getting this exception which is blocking my ability to save files in the IDE:

```
 Unable to rename '..\myunit.pas' to '..\__history\myunit.pas.~1~'.
```

MadExcept tells me this is happening in coreide100.bpl::

```
20a21bab +057 coreide100.bpl EditorForm     4256   +3 TryRename
20a21e0d +255 coreide100.bpl EditorForm     4297  +38 WriteEditorStream
20a52f46 +082 coreide100.bpl EditorBuffer   2633   +5 TEditBuffer.SaveFile
20a52c6d +005 coreide100.bpl EditorBuffer   2587   +1 TEditBuffer.Save
2097d128 +038 coreide100.bpl SourceModule    625   +2 TSourceModule.SaveFile
20a5ea9c +348 coreide100.bpl DocModul       1361  +61 TDocModule.Save
2097e1cf +117 coreide100.bpl SourceModule    970  +17 TSourceModule.Save
209b8792 +016 coreide100.bpl EditorControl  7485   +2 TEditEventHandler.EditSaveFile
209b4d91 +015 coreide100.bpl EditorControl  5672   +1 TCustomEditControl.SaveFile
```

I seem to remember there was something in the registry you could change to fix this.

Comment: Question1: can you do it manually without triggering some UAC?

Comment: Question2: do you still have that problem if you start Delphi as Administrator?

Comment: q1: yes. only ide complains. q2: no change. new factoid: only occurs on win 2008 r2 terminal services computer.

Comment: I ran into this problem when I have the file in question locked because I'm viewing it in Pascal Analyzer (6.3.0 in my case) in the bottom preview pane of that tool.

Comment: I just struck this problem for the first time ever - ironically it's right after restarting my computer and immediately after opening an FMX project (XE7), making one tiny change and attempting to save. This is on the same Windows 7 computer I do all my dev on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn it off in Tools\Options\Editor Options, "Create backup files".

Comment: Creating backup files is a useful feature. I would only recommend this as a temporary solution. Maybe restarting the IDE or rebooting the computer can solve this problem. It seems something is locking the \myunit.pas.~1~ file.

Comment: ...or the Windows Indexing Service, respective Windows Search in Win7

Comment: Windows Search is almost a virus. Try stopping the service, and it restarts it. Next they'll be re-enabling it when I disable it.

Answer (score 3):

Close the IDE. Download Process Explorer from sysinternals Press Ctrl+F and search for the filename which is locked. Once found, close the handle of that file

Comment: Not in all cases. Unfortunately, the only thing both procexp and sysinternals' handle.exe show as using it is bds.exe. And that's only while the project is open. So it's caused by some bug within Delphi. You can ALSO run into the problem if another program opens it, but it doesn't seem to be the typical case people are reporting because that ones easy to figure out and fix.

Answer (score 1):

Backup files *are* nice, so you probably do want to spend some time tracking down why they can't be saved. There are ill-behaved apps that nose around in changed files -- basically locking them while you're trying to get your work done. Off the top of my head: virus scanners (consider turning off scanning of your source folder) and Copernic Desktop (*great* local search app, but the @$#*! thing locks source and backup files while I'm editing them and the only "fix" is to shut down the search app, save the file, then reload the app). I dunno about Windows' own file indexer (like I said, Copernic is much nicer when it behaves) but if you have the indexer service running, try turning it off.

Comment: Backup files ARE nice except that I also have a mercurial repository and the most important thing backup files let me do is revert changes, which I already get from Mercurial. So I've decided to turn this off until I can figure out what dumb Windows feature is crashing my delphi IDE. I suspect Windows Search, which can't easily be told to ignore my backup files.